# Active Reports filterd data in subreport

Tags: c#, activereports

I want to create a report with two section ie, summary and detail. each is bind using different  datasets. Detail section using a subreport. Both are grouped on the same criteria

group1,group2
Summary fld 1
Summary fld 1

Details fld 1
Details fld 1

group1,group2
Summary fld 1
Summary fld 1

Details fld 1
Details fld 1

I cannot filter data in subreport-detail section.All data is coming there. I need to filter the dataset which bind the subreport on each grouping.
Through which event I can supply the filtered dataset

Comment: Are you using a DataSet as your data source, or something else? Also, are you using a code-based report file or an xml-based report file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gopu,

It looks like you wish to display the subreport content on the basis of the current group element in the main report. If this is the case then I think that passing a parameter from the main report to the subreport should help you achieve the desired results. You may want to check a nice blog article on passing parameters from main report to subreport at this [link](http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2012/04/activereport-for-dummies-passing.html).

If you need any further clarification or the provided solution does not gives you the expected results, please feel free to send your questions to powersupport@grapecity.com or post them on GrapeCity forums at www.datadynamics.com.

Thanks,

Sankalp